# how do I hide debug messages in third party node.js modules?

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-modules, nodemailer

I'm using the `nodemailer` npm module, which references the `mailcomposer` npm module, which in turn references the `mime` npm module. The mime module outputs a bunch of ugly, spammy debug messages if `process.env.DEBUG` is true.

Yes, I want debug messages, but only for MY code. How can I stop the mime module from outputting its own debug messages?

I've tried setting `process.env.DEBUG` (which the mime module looks at) to `false` right before requiring the `nodemailer` module, but it doesn't seem to affect the state of the mime module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to overwrite the process.stdout.write function?

Something like this:

```
var log = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.write = function (){};
```

Then, when you need to output something:

```
log ("my message to console");
```

Comment: I guess that could work, though it would interrupt any non-debug messages as well...